# Error calculating LST in QGIS

Tags: qgis, land-surface-temperature

I was using QGIS to calculate the LST of a city from Landsat 7 and 8 datasets. I was following online formulas to do the computation but I kept getting weird results (i.e. -17~62°C or 44~71°C; which is impossible for the temperature to be like this in the city). I tried using various datasets and different formulas, and even plugins (SCP) to do the calculation LST but all temperature values I got lay in a weird range. I wonder if anyone has experienced something similar before and knows what might be the problem?

[image: LST error]
[image: LST calculation]

Comment: Compare the results with [Landsat Science Product](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-collection-2-surface-temperature) (which has LST band, ST_B10) and see how "wrong" you are?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using wrong products in your formulas. In [this tutorial](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/deriving-temperature-from-landsat-8-thermal-bands-tirs/?rmedium=redirect&rsource=blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/01/06/deriving-temperature-from-landsat-8-thermal-bands-tirs), for Landsat 8, you can observe that, for brightness temperature calculation, you need to get radiance values for B10 band. So, for example, by using USGS Landsat 8 Collection 1 Tier 1 Raw Scenes, band 10 DN’s needs to be converted to TOA spectral radiance using the radiance rescaling factors in the MTL file.

By using a clipped b10 image for a little zone of Paris (2017-06-12), my formula in raster calculator of QGIS for brightness temperature was:

```
1321.08/ln((774.89/((0.0003342*"b10_DN_L8@1")+0.1))+1)-273.15
```

In following image can be observed that brightness temperatures ranged from 21 to 28 degrees as expected in a possibly Paris sunny day in June.

[image]

For calculating LST temperatures, NDVI was obtained with reflectances for B4, B5 bands as follows:

```
("b5_Rf_L8@1" -  "b4_Rf_L8@1")/("b5_Rf_L8@1" + "b4_Rf_L8@1")
```

surface emissivity ("emi@1") directly as:

```
0.004*(("ndvi@1" -  0.2)/0.3) + 0.986
```

and finally, LST temperatures with following formula:

```
"tb_L8@1" /  ( 1 + (10.895E-6 * "tb_L8@1" /1.438E-2) *  ln ( "emi@1"   ) )
```

Result was only slightly different of previously obtained for brightness temperatures; as it can be observed in following picture:

[image]